# Combined column data display only unique value

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

This is my source table. I want to combined column data and display unique data only.

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM DUMMY;

PLAN_CD              PLAN_NM              CLASS
-------------------- -------------------- ------
D01501               DENTAL               AA
D01501               DENTAL               AB
D01501               DENTAL               AC
V01501               VISION               AA
V01501               VISION               AB
```

And i want to ouput like this.

```
PLAN_CD              PLAN_NM              
-------              --------
D01501               DENTAL,AA,AB,AC              
V01501               VISION,AA,AB
```

I am using oracle 10g.Please give me query for oracle 10g.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy and **supported** built-in method for string aggregation in 10g. (Do not use `WM_CONCAT`, as it is not supported, and it is not available anymore in 12c.)

You need to write your own string aggregation function, for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE varchar2_ntt AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/

CREATE FUNCTION to_string (
                nt_in        IN varchar2_ntt,
                delimiter_in IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
                ) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

   v_idx PLS_INTEGER;
   v_str VARCHAR2(32767);
   v_dlm VARCHAR2(10);

BEGIN

   v_idx := nt_in.FIRST;
   WHILE v_idx IS NOT NULL LOOP
      v_str := v_str || v_dlm || nt_in(v_idx);
      v_dlm := delimiter_in;
      v_idx := nt_in.NEXT(v_idx);
   END LOOP;

   RETURN v_str;

END to_string;
/
```

Source is: http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=306

Your sample data:

```
create table dummy
(
  plan_cd varchar2(6 char),
  plan_nm varchar2(6 char),
  class varchar2(2 char)
);

insert into dummy values ('D01501', 'DENTAL', 'AA');
insert into dummy values ('D01501', 'DENTAL', 'AB');
insert into dummy values ('D01501', 'DENTAL', 'AC');
insert into dummy values ('V01501', 'VISION', 'AA');
insert into dummy values ('V01501', 'VISION', 'AB');
commit;
```

And finally the query:

```
select
  plan_cd,
  plan_nm || ',' 
  || to_string(cast(collect(class order by class) as varchar2_ntt)) as plan_nm
from
  dummy
group by
  plan_cd, plan_nm
;

PLAN_CD PLAN_NM                                
------- ----------------------------------------
D01501  DENTAL,AA,AB,AC                         
V01501  VISION,AA,AB
```

Answer (score 1):

In 9i and 10g, You can use `XMLAGG` function for string aggregation with this little trick as shown by [Donald K. Burleson](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_display_multiple_column_values_same_rows.htm)

```
select 
   (select department_name from HR.DEPARTMENTS where department_id=MTE.department_id) "DEPARTMENT_NAME", 
   (select first_name from hr.employees where employee_id = MTE.manager_id) "MANAGER_NAME",
   rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, first_name || ', ')).extract ('//text()'), ', ') "EMPLOYEES"
from 
   HR.EMPLOYEES MTE
group by 
   department_id, 
   manager_id
;
```

[XMLELEMENT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions220.htm): Produces an XML element "e" from each "first_name" row concatenated with a comma
[XMLAGG:](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions215.htm) Aggregates XML elements into a single row
[EXTRACT member function:](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/t_xml.htm#i1010715) Extracts xml values in varchar2()
[RTRIM:](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions141.htm) Removes last comma